# Как выбрать первые три элемента, потом пропустить один и снова выбрать три

Tags: css

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как с помощью css и nth-child сделать так, что бы выбирались первые три элемента, потом пропуск, потом снова 3 и т.д.

Пример:

- **Выбран**
- **Выбран**
- **Выбран**

- Пропущен

- **Выбран**
- **Выбран**
- **Выбран**
- Пропущен
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего так

```
:not(:nth-child(4n))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Решение было на поверхности, а я что то затупил (

Comment: Бывает. Рад помочь=)

Answer (score 0):

Да, дословно так:

```
<style>
    li{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    li:nth-child(4n) {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>Выбран</li>
    <li>Выбран</li>
    <li>Выбран</li>
    <li>Пропущен</li>
    <li>Выбран</li>
    <li>Выбран</li>
    <li>Выбран</li>
    <li>Пропущен</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:not(:nth-child(4n) {...styles}
```

почитай про [nth-child](http://www.css-tricks.ru/articles/css/how-nth-child-works), это не сложно